# How to find and replace a character and apply on a large file

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd, batch-processing

I am trying to replace a certain character found in convert.txt. Now, every characters found in convert.txt will replace into a linefeed in a file.

I have this code:

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in (convert.txt) do (
    Type c:\PETER\%%a  | repl.bat "\%%s" "%%s\n" X > c:\PETER\%%a
  )
```

I tried to use the replace.bat suggestion on this page see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir/16735079#16735079). Now, when I am trying to replace a large file's character into a line feed, the output is not complete. Do we have a limit on this case?

Comment: You can not read and write to the same file at the same time. You will need to send the output to different file.

Comment: @MCND

Thank you so much for the feedback :)

Answer (score 1):

As MC ND said in his comment, you cannot simultaneously read and write to the same file. You must write to a new file, and then replace the original with the new using MOVE.

```
for /f "delims=" %%s in (convert.txt) do (
  type "c:\PETER\%%a"  | repl.bat "\%%s" "%%s\n" X > "c:\PETER\%%a.new"
  move /y "c:\PETER\%%a.new" "c:\PETER\%%a" >nul
)
```

The MOVE operation is nearly instantaneous, no matter what the file size.